# How to Persist the PlaceHolder Value on PostBack in C#?

Tags: c#

I have a placeholder in gridview rowdatabound event, which holds a value but after some other button click during the postback the placeholder value is lost. Please suggest how can i persist the value after button click.

Comment: did you tried State management techniques ?

Comment: State Management techniques, may not come into the picture because the state management holds data for specific session, in my scenario it should be available all the times in placeholder

Comment: can you provide some code ?